# How i can get first range of IP address?

Tags: php, ip

I wanna show two first range of an IP. For example, I have 127.0.0.1. I wanna get 127.0 and use this example:

`127.0.0.1` show `127.0`
`192.168.1.6`  show `192.168`

How can I do that?

I tried `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` but it shows the whole IP address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [*explode*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php),

```
$nums = explode(".", "192.168.1.6") ;
echo $nums[0]. "." .$nums[1]; //192.168
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
 $your_ip = ...
 $split = preg_split ("/./",$your_ip,NULL);
 
 $your_new_ip = $split[0].".".$split[1];
```

Or [explode](https://www.php.net/explode)

```
 $your_ip = ... 
 $split = explode(".", $your_ip);
 $your_new_ip = $split[0].".".$split[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do like this:

```
substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],0,strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], '.',strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], '.')));
```

Comment: Testing your code, it returns ONLY the first part. Example: from 192.168.1.6 it shows 192